# Docker compose vs SDK

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a question regarding docker.
I was preparing devops infrastructure using docker compose.
I needed to create several environments (with different yaml configurations).

I have found some things a little bit cumbersome to do using docker-compose commands only.
I found [Docker SDK](https://docker-py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) for different languages here, it seems it fits my needs perfectly.

However, I have not seen such setup yet.

My question: are there any drawbacks with using mentioned docker api for organizing services ?

Thanks a lot.

P.S.: I have searched for such SDK for docker-compose. It does not exist, since docker-compose is only command line utility.

Comment: The main downside is going to be platform support I'd imagine. Any cloud provider is going to be able to take a docker-compose file and know what to do with it, the same can't be said for python scripts that set up docker. The other side to that is every software engineer worth their salt can use docker-compose at this point, the same, again, can't be said for Python + Docker SDK

Comment: Platform support is fine, services will be run on our own servers.

Comment: Then your only real problem is engineer familiarity and maintenance going forward afaik